# Missing an Operator

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

`"SELECT Users.Email FROM [Users] WHERE ((Users.Role) Like 'AO' AND (Users.Organization) Like " & Me.boOrgs & ")"`

I am getting the error missing operator but I have gone through this thing and not found anything missing.  I might just be missing something simple bu tI cannot find it and nobody works with me to ask to double check.

Comment: Missing single quotes around Me.bo0rgs

Comment: ...and if you're not going to use wildcards around 'AO' you may as well use `=` and not `LIKE`

Comment: Once I add the single quotes around " & Me.boOrgs & " I do not get anything in the recordset.  Witout the single quotes access at least fills the variable with what is in the form box.

Comment: If  `boOrgs` is a *string*, you will need the single quotes. If it is a number, no quotes are needed, but then the `like`-operator makes no sense.

Comment: boOrgs is a combo box on the form that the expression is from.  I have 10 different organizations that the combo box allows the user to select a single one and this string is pulling that selection in to finish the query and get the emails of the individual users belonging to that org.

Comment: `Like 'AO'` you need wildcards here if you're really checking for partial matches, so use `Like '*AO*'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless `Me.boOrgs` is already delimited by the single quotes, the concatenated query string will end like this:

`... AND (Users.Organization) Like MyOrganization)`

It should be `... AND (Users.Organization) Like 'MyOrganization')`

For this, you need to change the concatenation statement to `"SELECT Users.Email FROM [Users] WHERE ((Users.Role) Like 'AO' AND (Users.Organization) Like '" & Me.boOrgs & "')"`

Two side notes:

- Since your search criterion 'AO' has no wildcards, you should change `Like 'AO'` to `= 'AO'`
- Concatenating queries may be susceptible to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection); make sure to sanitize the content of Me.boOrgs carefully.